# Split constructor code in class body

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ somehow split constructor into multiple pieces in class body? Like in Scala or Kotlin? I need it for DSL written using C++ metaprogramming.

I have data members with non-trivial initialization sequence, and I want to specify initialization code together with members declaration.

Today I have:

```
class foo {
    foo() {
       // code to initialize a;
       a.something();  
       a.other_thing()
       // code to initialize b;
       b.other_thing(a);             
    }

    T a;     
    T b; 
};
```

Instead I want to specify initialization code together with member declaration, something like:

```
class foo {
    T a; 
    {
       a.something();  
       a.other_thing()
    }  

    T b; 
    {
       b.other_thing(a);             
    } 
};
```

I've found two solutions that I don't like.
First is to pass std::function parameter to every type, so I can initialize data members like this:

```
class foo {
    a{ [&](){
       // initialization code
    }};
};
```

Unfortunately this requires refactoring of all third-party libraries I use.

Second option is introducing a "dummy" data member just to execute lambda:

```
T a;
dummy_type a_init = [](&) { ... }
```

That can be hidden inside MACRO:

```
T a; INIT(a) { ... }
```

Everything is nice, but how can I create a zero-sized object in C++, so that each dummy initializer does not increase class size?

Comment: When writing `T a; {  }`, did you mean `T a;  foo(){  }`?

Comment: I find it unclear what you mean by *"split constructor into multiple pieces in class body"*, the fact that none of your code has a valid C++ constructor doesn't help. Please provide some (pseudo)code (that resembles valid C++) showcasing how you would like the syntax to look like

Comment: Why do you need a dummy member? Can't you just use the lambda to initialize `T a` directly? Can you show a concrete example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @UnholySheep I've updated question

Comment: It looks like you just need to use the **member initializer list** to initialize `a` before running the constructor body.

Comment: @Galik That way I will need to refactor T so it accepts lambda as a parameter. This is first solution I've described in question. Unfortunately I have legacy code that will be to painful to update.

Comment: I can see why to be honest, can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: @random: That is not true. Call the lambda where you define it and have it return whatever you like. You don't need to pass the lambda itself anywhere.

Comment: You can say `T a = [this]{ /* my weird init code here*/ return stuff; }();`

Comment: @Galik probably I don't know something about initializer_lists. So probably you have an answer I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Galik looks like solution! I will evaluate

Comment: What can you do in Scala or Kotlin? Can you maybe link an example?

Comment: @Zebrafish just read the docs. Scala allows specifying code directly inside class body. Kotlin constructors can be splitted in arbitrary number of blocks. But this question was solely about C++. I've made a reference just to proof that idea is not mad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lambda without any external changes if you call it immediately:

```
class foo
{
    foo()
    : a([=]() {
        T a;
        a.something();
        a.other_thing();
        return a;
    }())
    , b([=]() {
        T b;
        b.other_thing(a);
        return b;
    }())
    {}

    T a;     
    T b; 
};
```

Is it pretty? Hell no! But it should work, unless `T` is hard/impossible to move/copy.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/feef9c3223d523e6))

You can move the initialisers inline, too:

```
class foo
{
    T a = [=]() {
        T a;
        a.something();
        a.other_thing();
        return a;
    }();

    T b = [=]() {
        T b;
        b.other_thing(a);
        return b;
    }(); 
};
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca61a2c625efc21d))

Alternatively set up a factory function/type somewhere and just invoke that instead.

If you're really desperate, make the members `unique_ptr`s and resort to dynamic allocation like in the olden days (which you can scatter throughout your constructor body however you like). Probably the easiest solution tbh.

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
        a = std::make_unique<T>();
        a->something();
        a->other_thing();

        b = std::make_unique<T>();
        b->other_thing(*a);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> a;     
    std::unique_ptr<T> b; 
};
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96cfdfb1e1b25283))

Comment: Although now I'm wondering whether that `this->a` capture will work properly. Meh, just pass it in by reference otherwise.

Comment: Can I place it instead as @Galik suggests?  T a = []{ ... return a; }

Comment: @random: Try it and see.

Comment: Looks like T should be copy-constructable in this case?

Comment: @random: Yes, copyable or moveable, as I said in my answer

Comment: Will Galik's example of T a = [this]{ /* my weird init code here*/ return stuff; }();  work also?

Comment: So option 2 is the answer.  I don't see however how option 1 and option 3 relate to original question, it was about placing initialization code in same place in code where member is initialized.

Comment: @random In `C++17` I think you can get away with out having to be copy or moveable because of guaranteed copy elision.

Comment: @Galik mmm praps.

Comment: @Galik Looks like it works only for temporaries created in return statement.